# Eclipse PropertyPage enabling

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin, pde

I want to add a property page in eclipse via my plugin. This property page must be enabled only for projects of my nature. I have written the below code in plugin.xml

```xml
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
 <page
      class="com.test.me.ME"
      id="com.test.me.ME"
      name="ME">
     <and>
        <instanceof 
              value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
        </instanceof>
        <adapt
              type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
               <test
                    property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                    value="com.test.me.meprojectnature">
               </test>
    </adapt>
</and> 
 </page>
```

The above code works fine for the projects in project explorer and navigator view. But the same doesn't work in package Explorer view.

So, how to achieve the same functionality specific for package explorer view?

Answer (score 2):

You should move your instanceof check inside adapt.

Comment: Agreed.  As written, the node has to itself *be* an IProject in addition to being adaptable to something with your nature.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it but my opinion is that in your package explorer there aren't `org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject` elements, you should try whatever input you have (for example `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject`)

Comment: How should I tell that the check I am doing is for Package Explorer view.

Answer (score 1):

@nitind is right, you're specifying too many constraints. You want to say "Enabled when the selection is adaptable to an IProject and it's "projectNaure" property includes "my nature."

This should do it:

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
  <page
        name="My Property Page"
        class="some.package.MyPropertyPage"
        id="some.package.MyPropertyPage">
     <enabledWhen>
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
              <test
                 property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                 value="some.package.MyNatureID"/>
         </adapt>         
     </enabledWhen>
  </page>
```